# What is the internal storage being used for?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

My Android phone is showing me a notification saying that the "Phone storage is low". So, when I click on the notification, it shows me this:

[image]

The total space used is 6.59 GB, but the space used by the apps (which, I suppose, include cache and data as well as the application binaries). So what is using the other 6 GB!?

Android version: 4.2.2
Manufacturer: HTC

Comment: Not sure from the information given. There are apps that can help you track down just where your storage is being used, such as DiskUsage: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526

Answer (score 0):

...or you can go to android settings for free and select storage option and see which category takes most of your space. If you want to clean your cached files (you can do it directly from storage screen, just click on Cached data category), I recommend ES Task Manager, its free and in the combination with ES File Explorer he's best option, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

A good few GB is only your OS (android) then you have all that sometimes useless apps pre-installed on your phone + the apps you installed yourself it is not possible to say from that image but musics and photos usually take a large amount of MB if let to indefinitely accumulation especially if you use whatsapp/other apps.

Cache of apps can really take up alot of space if not cleared regularly(you would be surprised) use cache cleaner app
This is a major problem on androids because the internal memory is so low and you can't move apps to sd card so yeah its very annoying(i had to live with one with 2GB free only)

Clear your cache of apps using an app delete photos you don' want anymore uninstall apps you don't use anymore and if rooted uninstall all the blotware they forced on you is what you can do to get rid of that message.

Comment: I thought the cache was being accounted for in those 374.89 MB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know go to settings > storage and wait for it to load all of the used storage, but more than likely the majority of it is the android system itself and misc files.

If you find you aren't wasting a ton of space, you can double your space for 5 bucks.